# Deploying spine.js application on local Linux box

Tags: javascript, deployment, node.js, web, spine.js

I have written a simple web application using spine.js (node.js and hem procedure is followed). I have my development server running by executing "hem server" command. In order to deploy it, I first built the application using "hem build" and it succeeded with a message. Now when i refer to the docs at http://spinejs.com/docs/hem ; They have given the procedure for deploying it at heroku. How should i deploy it using node.js on a local Linux box running ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: Just now found out that in order to deploy the application, just expose the "public" directory in your project root folder using apache or nginx or any other webserver

Answer (score 2):

Just deploy the 'public' folder to your linux box. Serve it statically using Apache.